# Column width of a DataGrid in a Windows Mobile Application

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, datagrid, width

I'm having problems trying to adjust the width of a column of a datagrid. I used the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859464/what-is-the-datagrid-mappingname-for-a-non-datatable-datasource), but I can't solve it.

I'm using a List of objects as a datasource. In this simple example, I have just created a smart device application, and just added a datagrid. Then my code is this one:

```
    public Form1()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();

        List<Prueba> lista = new List<Prueba>();
        lista.Add(new Prueba("uno", "dos"));
        lista.Add(new Prueba("tres", "cuatro"));

        dataGrid1.DataSource = lista;
        DataGridTableStyle tableStyle = new DataGridTableStyle();
        tableStyle.MappingName = lista.GetType().ToString();
        DataGridTextBoxColumn tbcName = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
        tbcName.Width = 4000;
        tbcName.MappingName = "UNO";
        tbcName.HeaderText = "UNO";
        tableStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(tbcName);
        dataGrid1.TableStyles.Clear();
        dataGrid1.TableStyles.Add(tableStyle);
    }
}

public class Prueba
{
    public string UNO { get; set; }
    public string DOS { get; set; }

    public Prueba(string uno, string dos)
    {
        this.UNO = uno;
        this.DOS = dos;
    }
}
```

The width remains the same. Do you have a clue? Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this line

```
tableStyle.MappingName = lista.GetType().ToString();
```

to

```
tableStyle.MappingName = lista.GetType().Name;
```

Oh, and 4000 is a little big for a mobile but I assume that's a typo.

Comment: Ah thank you! Yes it works quite right.

Yes, the 4000 was just a value based on desperation :P

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using a DataTable as the DataSource instead of a list, it appears you have to change:

```
tableStyle.MappingName = lista.GetType().Name;
```

to:

```
tableStyle.MappingName = lista.TableName;
```

Took me a while to figure this out!