# How do i change the column width of a DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, datagrid, compact-framework

i'm creating a user control in C# .net compact framework 3.5.
And i'm using a DataGrid Control with a DataTable as the DataGrid's DataSource.
i need to make some of the grid columns wider.

for some reason i can't...

i just couldn't find the method or property that controls the column width...

any ideas?

thanks in advance...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051690/column-width-of-a-datagrid-in-a-windows-mobile-application

this is the closest i found to a solution to my problem and yet no cigar...

Comment: Made The solution from the link above this to work...
Solved thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `AutoSizeMode` and `Width` properties of the columns.

Comment: @OP: You should clearly tag/specify the technology you mean to avoid confusion. It takes a while to grok that you meant DataGrid, not DataGridView, and that you wrote DataSource, so it's not the WPF or Silverlight variant.

Comment: @George: We're talking ASP.NET here? In that case forget what I said, yes.

Comment: actually my bad it's in windows CE .net compact framework 3.5.
and i'm creating a user control.

Answer (score 1):

sample code below -

```
foreach(DataGridColumnStyle vColumnStyle in myGrid.TableStyles[0].GridColumnStyles )
{
    if (vColumnStyle.HeaderText.ToLower()=="mycolumn")    
    {                
        vColumnStyle.Width = 60;            
    }
}
```