# C# Compact Framework editable grid control (DataGrid?)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-cf-3.5

I want a grid control where I can specify the columns and allow the user to edit cell values.

Is there such a thing in CF3.5?

I'd prefer a standard control provided with VS 2008 if possible but I'll use a third party one if I have to.

I've tried DataGrid but can't see how to make it editable by the user or how to add an empty column of a certain width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Using the DataGrid in the .NET Compact Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172499%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> In the .NET Compact Framework, you cannot directly edit the contents
>   of the DataGrid at run time. You must bind controls, such as a
>   TextBox, to your data source and use the DataGrid to display and
>   select records.

From [How to: Use the DataGrid on the Pocket PC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229684%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> Alternatively, you can have Visual Studio generate summary and edit
>   forms automatically by selecting Generate Data Forms from the shortcut
>   menu for the smart tag on a DataGrid control.

There is also some other sample code (`VB.NET`) here:

[Designing GUI Applications with Windows Forms](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101720&seqNum=30)

Comment: I don't understand: "... selecting Generate Data Forms from the shortcut menu for the smart tag on a DataGrid control."

Comment: The smart tag appears in the Designer view of the form: [here's a sample](http://assets.devx.com/articlefigs/17242.jpg).

Comment: I don't get that menu. Does it matter that I'm Win CE?

Answer (score 1):

This explains how to add columns and set their widths in code:

[Column width of a DataGrid in a Windows Mobile Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051690/column-width-of-a-datagrid-in-a-windows-mobile-application)

Somehow I missed the DataGrid.TableStyles property, which allows columns to edited at design time.